# input value not getting read by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've spent days looking for an error in PHP only to discover my jQuery was never passing the correct value via AJAX in the first place.  I was 100% sure this worked and have tested in the past:

JS:

```
var barcode = null;
if ($("#barcode").length)
 { var $barcode = $("#barcode").val(); console.log("barcode"); }
alert(barcode);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="barcode" placeholder="Barcode">
</div>
```

Why does barcode still equal null when there are values in the barcode input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the variable you are assigning a value to is

```
$barcode
```

and you alert

```
barcode
```

Like in real life `$` matters

Comment: This is what happens when you spend two months on the same project.  I need to get out more. :/  The damning thing is, I'm noticing I'm using both `barcode` and `$barcode` in different JS functions related to this page. sloppy sloppy sloppy

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new variable, called `$barcode` inside of the `if` block. Your worker has no idea that you meant the `barcode` variable defined above. Instead, try `barcode =` instead of `var $barcode=`

Comment: Thank you guys for the assistance.  We like the easy questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are alerting barcode which is null. You would need $barcode